# Google Defer Subscription Internal Error 500

Tags: android, subscription, deferred

This code used to work about a month ago

```
PurchasesResource.SubscriptionsResource.DeferRequest request1 = purchase.Subscriptions.Defer(defRqst, gsPackageName, sSubscriptionName, sPurchaseToken);
```

I know the package name and subscription name are correct and thr token is passed across. The whole thing is in Alpha testing though, so could that be the issue. When it previously worked the whole testing regime offered by Google was different to now.

Does anybody know if you can test deferrals in a full alpha and beta testing environment or if things have changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

I do not often answer my own question but what I have discovered is that during testing you cannot seem to defer a subscription. I think this is because in testing every in-app billing subscription is set to a day, regardless of the period against the product. So if you try to defer a subscription by any period then it goes out beyond the testing period of 1 day and returns an error with no details other than 500 internal error. I could be completely wrong but nothing I could do would make it work.
So I thought, why not try it for real with the same code. So I bought one of my products and asked the system to defer for 16 days and it duly did. This is on a published product, but with the app in testing. All I did was remove myself from the testing users area, by removing my second gmail account I had set up for testing, from the Licensed Testing Gmail accounts under the settings tab for my google developer console. This forced a real purchase on the test app which I saw in under my orders in the merchant center.
So it would appear that the .NET client library [Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2/)

does at this point still work. I am not certain if it incorporates In-App billing V3 and have contacted the author to verify. At this point I have a response from someone who is not the author saying use the library that ends in V3 but this does not exist. I will update this once I know more.

But in summary, the only way I can get deferral to work is to use real subscriptions and not test ones.

Answer (score -1):

The In-app Billing Version 2 API has been deprecated in favor of the Version 3 API. If your app is using In-app Billing, please make sure that it is using the Version 3 API. If your app is still using the Version 2 API, you must migrate to the Version 3 API as soon as possible.

We plan to turn off the In-app Billing Version 2 service on January 27, 2015, after which time users will no longer be able to purchase in-app items and subscriptions through the Version 2 API. We strongly encourage and recommend you migrate your apps to use Version 3 API by November 2014, to provide ample time for users to update their apps to the new version.

For more details visit http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html

Comment: I am using the .NET API Client library. The latest version available through NuGet is Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2 last published on 23/07/2015. There does not seem to be a package for .NET for In-app billing V3 unless this incorporates V3, but at is not at all obvious.

Comment: OP is referring to the Google Play developer API not in-app billing API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/defer